# how to control datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Hello stackoverflow community,
i am learning c# gui datagrid part
so i created a datagrid and added two column headers as shown below:
[image: Datagrid view]

Now i have this value of a class

```
 Program.AllStudents[Form1.userId].name;
```

Also i clicked on the datagrid and this function appeared

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{


}
```

But I want my changes to appear once the form of datagrid is loaded not onclick

i want to add it for the name column,what should i do?
also the columns are editable so i want to know how to access them later

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DataGrid 'loaded' event like this:

xaml:

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGridView1" 
  Loaded="dataGridView1_OnLoaded"
>
```

c#:

```
private void dataGridView1_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.ItemsSource = Program.AllStudents[Form1.userId].name;
}
```